# Editor Persons Who Copy/Paste From Word

Tags: nodes, 6

We have many editors that are going to submit documents for appearance on our website. Most documents come in the form of a .doc etc. What would be the best method of importing the text into a content node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WYSIWYG](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) + [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) provides a "Paste from word" option; it doesn't do any automated importing, but does provide a popup window containing a textarea for the user to paste from word. The pasted content is then cleaned up and converted to HTML, and finally placed in the WYSIWYG as normal content.

Comment: How can we force to "paste as plain text"? this will import from word the format as well isn't it?

Comment: You have to implement `hook_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter()`...`function MYMODULE_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter(&$settings, $context) { if ($context['profile']->editor == 'ckeditor') { $settings['forcePasteAsPlainText'] = TRUE } }`

Comment: Thanks Clive, but what If I'm not using ckeditor? should i change 'ckeditor' with the name of the other library?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried [CKeditor](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor)
it's a stand alone module, it does not depend on WYSIWYG.
Download it and install it, then go to [CKeditor website](http://ckeditor.com/download) and download the library.
I had troubles with the CKeditor for drupal in the [CKeditor website](http://ckeditor.com/download), so i suggest you do download just the CKeditor (the first one), then extract the content of ckeditor folder into modules/ckeditor/ckeditor.

This module provides you a lot of functionalities such as 'force paste as plain text', 'check spelling on typing' and others. I found it more complete than WYSIWYG module with different libraries such as Tinymce, FCKeditor and CKeditor.